# What are the exact steps to read a csv file into an multidimensional array in Node.js?

Tags: node.js

I have the following data in a .csv file:

```
Smith,Tom,43
Johnson,Sue,28
Sommers,Jeff,44
```

I would like to populate a multi-dimensional array with this data so that:

```
array[0][0] == Smith
array[1][2] == 28
etc.
```

Comment: http://www.adaltas.com/projects/node-csv/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using the [csv](https://github.com/wdavidw/node-csv) module -

```
var csv = require('csv');
var people = [];
var filePath = 'path/to/my/awesome/csv/file.csv';
csv()
.from.path(filePath)
.to.array(function(data) {
    data.forEach(function(person, index) {
        people[index] = [];
        people[index][0] = person[0];
        people[index][1] = person[1];
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I also tried the following (using [**ya-csv**](https://www.npmjs.org/package/ya-csv) ) and like it as well:

```
function readFile() {
    var $IN = require('ya-csv');
    var $filePath = 'data.csv';
    var $people = [];
    var $reader = $IN.createCsvFileReader($filePath, {
        'separator': ','
    });
    $reader.on('data', function(item) {
        $people.push(item);
    })
}
```