# What are the exact steps to write a multidimensional array to a csv file in Node.js?

Tags: node.js

I want to be able to do the reverse of this question/answer: [What are the exact steps to read a csv file into an multidimensional array in Node.js?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22562808/what-are-the-exact-steps-to-read-a-csv-file-into-an-md-array-in-node-js/22562940#22562940)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First get ya-csv:

```
npm install ya-csv
```

Now you can do the following:

```
var out = require('ya-csv');
var writer = writer.createCsvFileWriter('data.csv', {
     'quote': ''
});
people.forEach(function(item) {
     writer.writeRecord(item);
});
```

If your MD array looked like this:

```
[Smith][Sally][42]
[Jones][Don][55]
```

Then your .csv file will look like this:

```
Smith,Sally,42
Jones,Don,55
```